# subsetting data.frame without column names

Tags: r

```
test <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
MEMORY1 MEMORY2 MEMORY3 MEMORY4 MEMORY5 MEMORY6 MEMORY7 MEMORY8
7.5     5.      5.      2.      7.5     2.      2.      5.
6.      7.5     3.5     1.5     3.5     5.      1.5     7.5
6.      3.      3.      3.      3.      7.5     3.      7.5
3.5     3.5     3.5     3.5     3.5     7.5     3.5     7.5
5.      5.      5.      1.      5.      5.      5.      5.
5.      5.      2.      2.      7.      5.      2.      8.
")
```

I have a data.frame, and I would like to subset just the first row. If I do `test[1, ]`, the result is

```
> test[1, ]
  MEMORY1 MEMORY2 MEMORY3 MEMORY4 MEMORY5 MEMORY6 MEMORY7 MEMORY8
1     7.5       5       5       2     7.5       2       2       5
```

How do I subset the data.frame so that I get just a vector of the numbers without the column names?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you want is a numeric vector instead of a data.frame.  For this, you can just use `as.numeric` to do the conversion

```
> as.numeric(df[1,])
[1] 7.5 5.0 5.0 2.0 7.5 2.0 2.0 5.0
```

Comment: What if the data are not all numeric?

Comment: If the data are not all numeric, then it depends on what the desired behavior is. In R, vectors are always homogeneous -- all elements are the same type. You could use `as.list` to create a list from the column values, but it would depend on the specific use case. Probably worth asking a question with your particular use case if you don't find anything that looks right. Feel free to add a link here (in the comments) so that I'll see it and to help others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `unlist` with option `use.names=FALSE` to return only `vector` without names.

```
unlist(test[1,], use.names=FALSE)
#[1] 7.5 5.0 5.0 2.0 7.5 2.0 2.0 5.0
```

`test[1,]` is still a `data.frame` with 8 columns.  A `data.frame` can be regarded as a `list` having the same `length` for its `list` elements (or columns).  So we can use `unlist`.  This also works when you are creating a `vector` from more than one row.

```
unlist(test[1:2,], use.names=FALSE)
```

Or as @Frank suggested, if we are subsetting multiple rows by keeping the dimensions, we set the names to `NULL` and convert to `matrix`.

```
 as.matrix(setNames(test[1:2,],NULL))
```

Comment: Regarding the second part, I think that that isn't really "subsetting" (from the OP's title), since the dimensions change. Maybe `as.matrix(setNames(test[1:2,],NULL))` or the goofier `\`dimnames<-\`(as.matrix(test[1:2,]),NULL)`

Comment: An alternative to `setNames` for the `as.matrix` version is the utility function `unname`

Comment: I like @user295691 method with `unname` (i.e. `unname(as.matrix(test[1:2,]))`) since you aren't left with the `dimnames` attribute as `NULL`.